# How to control the enter keydown in Primefaces wizard tabs?

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

I have one Primefaces Wizard in my application for the creation of invoices, which is working very well.

This is the complete source code for the second Wizard tab:

```
<p:tab id="FormDataTabview" title="Customer datas">                

            <p:focus context="FormDataTabview" for="zipCode"/>
            <p:defaultCommand id="defaultCommand2" scope="FormDataTabview" target="NextBtn2"/>

            <p:panel styleClass="ui-fluid" style="background: #{userController.headerColor}"  rendered="#{not empty formController.selected}">

                <p:panelGrid columns="8" columnClasses="ui-grid-col-1,ui-grid-col-4,ui-grid-col-2,ui-grid-col-1,ui-grid-col-2,ui-grid-col-1,ui-grid-col-2" layout="grid" styleClass="ui-panelgrid-blank">    

                    <p:outputLabel value="#{bundle.EditFormLabel_partnerDataId}" 
                                   styleClass="biggerText"
                                   rendered="#{formController.getRendered('partnerId', formController.selected.type)}" for="partnerId" />

                    <p:inputText  rendered="#{formController.getRendered('partnerId', formController.selected.type)}" 
                                  disabled="true"
                                  value="#{formController.selected.partnerDataId.name}" 
                                  styleClass="biggerText" /> 

                    <p:outputLabel/>

                    <p:outputLabel value="#{bundle.EditFormLabel_formNr}" />
                    <p:inputText disabled="true" value="#{formController.selected.formNr}" title="#{bundle.EditFormTitle_formNr}" />
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{bundle.EditFormLabel_formDate}" for="formDate" />
                    <p:inputText disabled="true" value="#{formController.selected.formDate}" >
                        <f:convertDateTime locale="hu" timeZone="Europe/Budapest" />
                    </p:inputText>

                </p:panelGrid>                    

                <p:panelGrid columns="9" columnClasses="ui-grid-col-1,ui-grid-col-2,ui-grid-col-2,ui-grid-col-2,ui-grid-col-1,ui-grid-col-2,ui-grid-col-1,ui-grid-col-2" layout="grid" styleClass="ui-panelgrid-blank">    
                    <p:outputLabel/>
                    <p:inputText disabled="true" value="#{typeListController.getTypeLabelByNameValue(formType.concat('.type'),formController.selected.type)}" />
                    <p:inputText disabled="true" value="#{typeListController.getTypeLabelByNameValue(formType.concat('.direction'),formController.selected.direction)}" />
                    <p:outputLabel />
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{bundle.EditFormLabel_currency}" />
                    <p:inputText disabled="true" value="#{formController.selected.currency}" />
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{bundle.EditFormLabel_deliveryDate}" for="formDate" />
                    <p:inputText disabled="true" value="#{formController.selected.deliveryDate}" >
                        <f:convertDateTime locale="hu" timeZone="Europe/Budapest" />
                    </p:inputText>

                </p:panelGrid>
                <p:panelGrid columns="8" columnClasses="ui-grid-col-1,ui-grid-col-1,ui-grid-col-1,ui-grid-col-4,ui-grid-col-1,ui-grid-col-2,ui-grid-col-1,ui-grid-col-2" layout="grid" styleClass="ui-panelgrid-blank">    
                    <p:outputLabel/>
                    <p:inputText disabled="true" value="#{typeListController.getTypeLabelByNameValue(formType.concat('.subtype'),formController.selected.subtype)}" />
                    <p:inputText disabled="true" value="#{formController.prefix}" />
                    <p:outputLabel/>
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{bundle.EditFormLabel_paymentType}" />
                    <p:inputText disabled="true" value="#{typeListController.getTypeLabelByNameValue('form.payment_type',formController.selected.paymentType)}" />  
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{bundle.EditFormLabel_paymentDate}" />
                    <p:inputText disabled="true" value="#{formController.selected.paymentDate}" >
                        <f:convertDateTime locale="hu" timeZone="Europe/Budapest" />
                    </p:inputText>                        

                </p:panelGrid>                    

            </p:panel>

            <div class="ui-fluid" >
                <p:panelGrid id="grid5" columns="3" columnClasses="ui-grid-col-6,ui-grid-col-4,ui-grid-col-2"  layout="grid" styleClass="ui-panelgrid-blank" 
                             rendered="#{not empty formController.selected}">    

                    <p:panel id="addressPanel" class="normal-height lightgrey">

                        <p:selectOneButton id="addressButton" value="#{formController.selectedAddress}">
                            <f:selectItems value="#{formController.selected.partnerId.addressCollection}" var="address" itemLabel="#{address.toString()}" itemValue="#{address}" />
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Új cím" value="#{null}" noSelectionOption="true" />
                            <p:ajax listener="#{formController.changeAddress}" update="addressPanel"/>
                        </p:selectOneButton>
                        <p:panelGrid columns="4" columnClasses="ui-grid-col-2,ui-grid-col-2,ui-grid-col-5,ui-grid-col-3" layout="grid" styleClass="ui-panelgrid-blank">    


                            <p:outputLabel value="#{bundle.EditAddressLabel_city}" for="city" />
                            <p:autoComplete id="zipCode"
                                            required="#{formController.zipCodeRequired(formController.selected.partnerId)}"
                                            requiredMessage="#{bundle.CreateAddressRequiredMessage_zipCode}"
                                            value="#{formController.selected.addressDataId.zipCode}" 
                                            completeMethod="#{zipAddressController.completeZip}" 
                                            forceSelection="false"      
                                            disabled="#{formController.selected.direction == 3}"
                                            scrollHeight="200" queryDelay="1000"
                                            var="zipItem" 
                                            itemLabel="#{zipAddressController.getZipByCodeString(zipItem)}"
                                            itemValue="#{zipItem}" 
                                            autoHighlight="true">
                                <p:ajax event="itemSelect" listener="#{formController.changeZip(zipAddressController.getZipByCode(formController.selected.addressDataId.zipCode))}" update="city"/>     

                            </p:autoComplete>
                            <p:inputText id="city" required="true" requiredMessage="#{bundle.EditZipAddressRequiredMessage_city}" disabled="#{formController.selected.subtype eq 3 or formController.selected.subtype eq  2 or formController.selected.direction == 3}" 
                                         value="#{formController.selected.addressDataId.city}" title="#{bundle.EditAddressTitle_city}" />
                            <p:commandButton id="editAddrButton" immediate="true"  icon="ui-icon-pencil" update="AddressDataEditForm" oncomplete="PF('AddressDataEditDialog').show()"/>

                        </p:panelGrid>
                        <p:panelGrid columns="3" columnClasses="ui-grid-col-2,ui-grid-col-8,ui-grid-col-2" layout="grid" styleClass="ui-panelgrid-blank">    

                            <p:outputLabel value="#{bundle.EditAddressLabel_street}" for="street" />
                            <p:inputText id="street" required="true" requiredMessage="#{bundle.EditZipAddressRequiredMessage_street}" disabled="#{formController.selected.subtype eq 3 or formController.selected.subtype eq  2 or formController.selected.direction == 3}" value="#{formController.selected.addressDataId.street}" title="#{bundle.EditAddressTitle_street}" />
                            <p:selectOneMenu id="typeOfStreet" editable="true"  value="#{formController.selected.addressDataId.typeOfStreet}" title="#{bundle.EditAddressTitle_typeOfStreet}" >
                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="utca" itemValue="utca" />
                                ...
                            </p:selectOneMenu>                        
                        </p:panelGrid>

                        <p:panelGrid columns="6" columnClasses="ui-grid-col-2,ui-grid-col-2,ui-grid-col-2,ui-grid-col-2,ui-grid-col-2,ui-grid-col-2" layout="grid" styleClass="ui-panelgrid-blank">    
                            <p:outputLabel value="#{bundle.EditAddressLabel_number}" for="number" />
                            <p:inputText id="number" disabled="#{formController.selected.subtype eq 3 or formController.selected.subtype eq  2}" value="#{formController.selected.addressDataId.number}" title="#{bundle.EditAddressTitle_number}" />
                            <p:inputText id="building" disabled="#{formController.selected.subtype eq 3 or formController.selected.subtype eq  2}" value="#{formController.selected.addressDataId.building}" title="#{bundle.EditAddressTitle_building}" />
                            <p:inputText id="stairway" disabled="#{formController.selected.subtype eq 3 or formController.selected.subtype eq  2}" value="#{formController.selected.addressDataId.stairway}" title="#{bundle.EditAddressTitle_stairway}" />
                            <p:inputText id="floor" disabled="#{formController.selected.subtype eq 3 or formController.selected.subtype eq  2}" value="#{formController.selected.addressDataId.floor}" title="#{bundle.EditAddressTitle_floor}" />
                            <p:inputText id="door" disabled="#{formController.selected.subtype eq 3 or formController.selected.subtype eq  2}" value="#{formController.selected.addressDataId.door}" title="#{bundle.EditAddressTitle_door}" />
                        </p:panelGrid>
                    </p:panel>





                    <p:panel  id="taxPanel" class="normal-height lightgrey">


                        <p:panelGrid  columns="2" columnClasses="ui-grid-col-6,ui-grid-col-6" layout="grid" >    
                            <p:outputLabel value="#{bundle.CreatePartnerLabel_taxNumber}" for="partnerTaxNumber"/> 
                            <p:inputMask id="partnerTaxNumber" value="#{formController.selected.partnerDataId.taxNumber}" mask="99999999-9-99"/>                                                                

                           ...
                        </p:panelGrid>
                    </p:panel>

                    <p:panelGrid>
                        <p:panel id="grid4" class="normal-height lightgrey" rendered="#{formType == 'invoice' or formType == 'orders' or formType == 'shipment'}">
                            <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="euInternalBoo" itemLabel="#{bundle.EditFormLabel_euInternalBoo}" value="#{formController.selected.euInternalBoo}" required="true" requiredMessage="#{bundle.EditFormRequiredMessage_euInternalBoo}">                    
                                <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{formController.changeEuInternal}" update="taxPanel"/>
                            </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
                            <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="foreignLangBoo" 
                                                     disabled="#{formController.selected.subtype eq 3 or formController.selected.subtype eq  2}" 
                                                     value="#{formController.selected.foreignLangBoo}" 
                                                     itemLabel="#{bundle.EditFormLabel_foreignLangBoo}"
                                                     required="true" requiredMessage="#{bundle.EditFormRequiredMessage_foreignLangBoo}"/>
                            <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="reverseChargeBoo" itemLabel="#{bundle.ListFormTitle_reverseCharge}" disabled="#{formController.selected.subtype eq 3 or formController.selected.subtype eq  2}" value="#{formController.selected.reverseChargeBoo}" required="true"/>
                            <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="moveInventory" itemLabel="#{bundle.ListFormTitle_moveInventory}" rendered="#{formType == 'invoice'}" value="#{formController.selected.moveInventory}" required="false"/>
                        </p:panel>
                        <c:if test="#{formType == 'facilityForm' and formController.direction == 1}">
                            <p:panel id="grid4f" class="normal-height lightgrey">
                                <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="facilityFormX" itemLabel="X" value="#{formController.selected.moveInventoryNegated}" required="false"/>
                            </p:panel>
                        </c:if>

                    </p:panelGrid>

                    <p:panel class="small-height lightgrey"                                 
                             rendered="#{not formController.getRendered(&quot;Deposit&quot;,formController.selected.type)}">

                        <p:panelGrid columns="2" columnClasses="ui-grid-col-4,ui-grid-col-8" layout="grid" styleClass="ui-panelgrid-blank">    

                            <p:outputLabel value="#{bundle.EditFormLabel_FacilityIdFrom}" for="facilityIdFrom"
                                           rendered="#{formController.selected.direction eq 1 or formController.selected.direction eq 3}"/>
                            <p:selectOneMenu id="facilityIdFrom"
                                             value="#{formController.selected.facilityIdFrom}"
                                             required="#{formController.getRequired('facilityIdFrom',formController.selected.type)}"
                                             requiredMessage="#{bundle.EditFormRequiredMessage_facilityIdFrom}"
                                             disabled="#{formController.selected.subtype eq 3 or formController.selected.subtype eq  2 or formController.selected.formItemCollection.size() ne 0}"
                                             rendered="#{formController.selected.direction eq 1 or formController.selected.direction eq 3}"
                                             filter="true"
                                             filterMatchMode="contains">
                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{bundle.SelectOneMessage}" noSelectionOption="true"/>
                                <f:selectItems value="#{facilityController.items}"
                                               var="facilityIdFromItem"
                                               itemValue="#{facilityIdFromItem}"
                                               itemLabel="#{facilityIdFromItem.name}"
                                               /> 
                                <p:ajax event="change" update="containerIdFrom"/>
                            </p:selectOneMenu>  
                            <p:outputLabel value="#{bundle.EditFormLabel_ContainerIdFrom}"
                                           for="containerIdFrom" 
                                           rendered="#{formController.selected.direction eq 1 or formController.selected.direction eq 3}"/>
                            <p:selectOneMenu id="containerIdFrom" disabled="#{formController.selected.subtype eq 3 or formController.selected.subtype eq  2 or formController.selected.formItemCollection.size() ne 0}"
                                             value="#{formController.selected.containerIdFrom}" 
                                             required="#{formController.getRequired('containerIdFrom',formController.selected.type)}"
                                             requiredMessage="#{bundle.EditFormRequiredMessage_containerIdFrom}"
                                             rendered="#{formController.selected.direction eq 1 or formController.selected.direction eq 3}" filter="true" filterMatchMode="contains"> 
                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{bundle.SelectOneMessage}" noSelectionOption="true"/>
                                <f:selectItems value="#{formController.selected.facilityIdFrom.containerCollection}"
                                               var="containerIdFromItem"
                                               itemValue="#{containerIdFromItem}"
                                               itemLabel="#{containerIdFromItem.name}"
                                               />
                            </p:selectOneMenu>

                            <p:outputLabel value="#{bundle.EditFormLabel_FacilityIdTo}" for="facilityIdTo"
                                           rendered="#{formController.selected.direction eq 2 or formController.selected.direction eq 3}"/>
                            <p:selectOneMenu id="facilityIdTo" disabled="#{formController.selected.subtype eq 3 or formController.selected.subtype eq  2 or formController.selected.formItemCollection.size() ne 0}"
                                             value="#{formController.selected.facilityIdTo}"
                                             required="#{formController.getRequired('facilityIdTo',formController.selected.type)}"
                                             requiredMessage="#{bundle.EditFormRequiredMessage_facilityIdTo}"
                                             rendered="#{formController.selected.direction eq 2 or formController.selected.direction eq 3}"
                                             filter="true"
                                             filterMatchMode="contains">
                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{bundle.SelectOneMessage}" noSelectionOption="true"/>
                                <f:selectItems value="#{facilityController.items}"
                                               var="facilityIdToItem"
                                               itemValue="#{facilityIdToItem}"
                                               itemLabel="#{facilityIdToItem.name}"
                                               /> 
                                <p:ajax event="change" update="containerIdTo"/>
                            </p:selectOneMenu>  
                            <p:outputLabel value="#{bundle.EditFormLabel_ContainerIdTo}"
                                           for="containerIdTo" 
                                           rendered="#{formController.selected.direction eq 2 or formController.selected.direction eq 3}"/>
                            <p:selectOneMenu id="containerIdTo" disabled="#{formController.selected.subtype eq 3 or formController.selected.subtype eq  2 or formController.selected.formItemCollection.size() ne 0}"
                                             value="#{formController.selected.containerIdTo}" 
                                             required="#{formController.getRequired('containerIdTo',formController.selected.type)}"
                                             requiredMessage="#{bundle.EditFormRequiredMessage_containerIdTo}"
                                             rendered="#{formController.selected.direction eq 2 or formController.selected.direction eq 3}" filter="true" filterMatchMode="contains"> 
                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{bundle.SelectOneMessage}" noSelectionOption="true"/>
                                <f:selectItems value="#{formController.selected.facilityIdTo.containerCollection}"
                                               var="containerIdToItem"
                                               itemValue="#{containerIdToItem}"
                                               itemLabel="#{containerIdToItem.name}"
                                               />
                            </p:selectOneMenu>
                        </p:panelGrid>
                    </p:panel>

                    <p:panel id="depositPanel" class="normal-height lightgrey" rendered="#{formController.getRendered(&quot;Deposit&quot;,formController.selected.type) and formController.selected.formItemCollection ne null and formController.selected.formItemCollection.get(0) ne null}">
                        <p:panelGrid id="Deposit" columns="2">                                
                            <p:outputLabel value="#{bundle.Deposit}" styleClass="biggerText"/>
                            <p:outputLabel/>
                            <p:outputLabel value="#{bundle.ListFormItemSumLabel_netMoney}" for="netPriceDeposit" />
                            <p:inputText id="netPriceDeposit" value="#{formController.selected.formItemCollection.get(0).netUnitPrice}" title="#{bundle.EditFormItemTitle_netPrice}">
                                <f:convertNumber minFractionDigits="0" maxFractionDigits="3" />
                            </p:inputText>
                            <p:outputLabel value="#{bundle.EditFormItemLabel_vatRate}" for="vatRateDeposit" />
                            <p:inputText id="vatRateDeposit" disabled="#{formController.selected.euInternalBoo}"  value="#{formController.selected.formItemCollection.get(0).vatRate}" title="#{bundle.EditFormItemTitle_vatRate}" />
                            <p:outputLabel value="#{bundle.ListFormItemSumLabel_grossMoney}" for="grossMoneyDeposit"/>
                            <p:inputText id="grossMoneyDeposit" value="#{formController.selected.formItemCollection.get(0).grossUnitPrice}">
                                <f:convertNumber minFractionDigits="0" maxFractionDigits="3" />
                            </p:inputText>
                        </p:panelGrid>
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                                $("##{formType}EditForm").keyup(function(e) {
                                        if(e.which == 13 || e.keyCode == 13)
                                        {
                                            PF('NextBtn2').jq.click();
                                        }
                                });
                        </script>
                    </p:panel>
                    <p:panel id="documentPanel" class="small-height lightgrey">
                        ...
                    </p:panel>

                </p:panelGrid>             
            </div>

            <p:commandButton style="float :left" class="default-height" value="Alapadatok" icon="ui-icon-arrow-1-w" iconPos="left" onclick="PF('myWizard').back();" />
            <p:commandButton id="NextBtn2" class="redbutton default-height" style="float :right" 
                             rendered="#{not formController.getRendered(&quot;Deposit&quot;,formController.selected.type)}"
                             value="Form items" icon="ui-icon-arrow-1-e" 
                             actionListener="#{formController.createFormItemWithSaveForm(true)}" update=":center,:growl"
                             iconPos="right" oncomplete="PF('myWizard').next(); javascript:saved=true" />


            <p:menuButton id="FinalButton1" style="float :right; margin: 10px!important" icon="ui-icon-check" value="Finalize"
                          rendered="#{formController.getRendered(&quot;Deposit&quot;,formController.selected.type)}">
                <p:menuitem oncomplete="javascript:saved=true" 
                            action="#{formController.setFinal}"  
                            disabled="#{formController.selected.status == 2 or formController.selected.id eq 0}" 
                            value="#{bundle.Finalize}" 
                            update=":center,:growl" 
                            icon="ui-icon-check"/>
                <p:menuitem rendered="#{formType=='invoice' and formController.selected.paymentType == 1}" 
                            update="@([id$=CheckoutCreateForm]),:center" 
                            oncomplete="PF('CheckoutCreateDialog').show()"  
                            action="#{invoiceController.createCheckout()}" 
                            disabled="#{formController.selected.status == 2 or formController.selected.id eq 0}" 
                            value="#{bundle.Finalize} &amp; #{bundle.ViewCheckoutTitle}" 
                            icon="ui-icon-check"/>
                <p:menuitem value="Send" 
                            rendered="#{formType=='invoice'}" 
                            disabled="#{formController.selected.id eq 0}" 
                            actionListener="#{formController.sendEmail()}" 
                            update=":center,:growl" 
                            icon="ui-icon-mail-closed">
                    <p:confirm icon="ui-icon-alert" message="Sending to #{formController.selected.partnerDataId.email} address?"/>
                </p:menuitem>                
                <p:menuitem oncomplete="javascript:saved=true" 
                            action="#{formController.save}" 
                            actionListener="#{formController.navigateForm()}" 
                            value="Make draft" 
                            disabled="#{formController.selected.status == 2}" 
                            update=":center,:growl"  
                            icon="ui-icon-disk"/>
                <p:separator />
                <p:menuitem value="Delete" 
                            icon="ui-icon-close" 
                            action="#{formController.destroy}" 
                            actionListener="#{formController.navigateForm()}" 
                            update=":center,:growl" />
            </p:menuButton>

        </p:tab>
```

The problem is I can't control the defaultCommand (which should be the ENTER key) on all wizard tabs, because the

```
<p:defaultCommand id="defaultCommand2" target="NextBtn2"/>
```

on the second wizard tab (which I had copied here) isn't working, I don't know why. It jumps to the next wzard tab, but the actionListener on the target button (NextBtn2) isn't called at all. So I need a workaround and I'm trying with jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $("##{formType}EditForm\\:grid5").keyup(function(e) {
                if(e.which == 13 || e.keyCode == 13)
                {
                    PF('NextBtn2').jq.click();
                }
        });
</script>
```

I'm using the PF('ID-OF-THE-BUTTON').jq.click() in other views, this is working I know that, but how to filter out the ENTER keypress and to work only in this tab (in grid5)... sadly I don't know :( How can I do that because right now this isn't doing anything.

Thank you very much!

Comment: I think its your use of default command.  A wizard is just CSS its not reloading the page so the Default Command on your Wizard Page 1 is probably still in effect.

Comment: Oh, great...so in Wizard, there could be only one defaultCommand? I'm still out of idea how to make this to work :(

Comment: You could analyze the JS of Default Command and just write your own similar JS to meet your needs of the wizard: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/master/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/forms/forms.defaultcommand.js

Comment: I just checked, the "action" and the "actionListener" on the first defaultCommand target, these methods are doesn't called if I press ENTER on the second tab, so I think it's not the first defaultCommand which is executed.

Comment: Okay, so the JS approach could work, but there I want to ask for help, because I'm not good at JS, especially in Primefaces context. I pasted what I tried but this isn't working and this isn't yet limited for the second tab only (could $("##{formType}EditForm\\:grid5") work?!).

Answer (score 1):

I had to access the target button via widgetVar attribute. This way it works:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery("##{formType}EditForm\\:grid5").keyup(function(e) {
        if(e.which == 13 || e.keyCode == 13)
        {
            PF("NextButton2").jq.click();
        }
});
</script>
```